# Template specialization for class wrappers

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I can't have my `int` class wrapper acting like a primitive `int` in template specialization.

I've prepared this code to explain my issue in detail:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 

class Integer
{
  int _v;
public:
  constexpr explicit Integer(int v) : _v(v) {}
  constexpr Integer next() const { return Integer(_v + 1); }
  constexpr operator int() const { return _v;}
};

static constexpr auto integer1 = Integer(1);
static constexpr auto integer2a = Integer(2);
static constexpr auto integer2b = integer1.next();

template <const Integer& i>
void foo_Integer()
{
  static auto foo_id = rand();
  std::cout << foo_id << std::endl;
}

static constexpr auto int1 = 1;
static constexpr auto int2a = 2;
static constexpr auto int2b = int1 + 1;

template <int i>
void foo_int()
{
  static auto foo_id = rand();
  std::cout << foo_id << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  foo_int<int1>();
  foo_int<int2a>();
  foo_int<int2b>(); // same template specialization as above -> :)

  foo_Integer<integer1>();
  foo_Integer<integer2a>();
  foo_Integer<integer2b>(); // different template specialization -> :(
}
```

As you can see running the code

```
foo_int<int2a>();
foo_int<int2b>();
```

use the same template specialization, while

```
foo_Integer<integer2a>();
foo_Integer<integer2b>();
```

use different template specializations.

This is, of course, correct, from the compiler point of view, since the template accepts a `const Integer&`, but I hope there are other better approaches to workaround the issue.

Comment: fwiw, `foo_int<integer2a>;` and `foo_int<integer2b>;` are the same function

Comment: Just a note on terminology, that's template instantiations, not template specializations.

Comment: @super - No, that's actually correct terminology. The standard refers to instantiated templates as specializations too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily make `Integer` a structural type (C++20). Then its values are valid template parameters.

```
class Integer
{
public:
  int _v;

  constexpr explicit Integer(int v) : _v(v) {}
  constexpr Integer next() const { return Integer(_v + 1); }
  constexpr operator int() const { return _v;}
};

template <Integer i>
void foo_Integer()
{
  static auto foo_id = rand();
  std::cout << foo_id << std::endl;
}
```

[Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/edWIreD0mlzwkIWC)

And the values would be equivalent, even if they come from objects with different identities.

Comment: That's gold. I wonder if there is a way to make "_v" private. Maybe defining a specific comparison operator?

Comment: @c.bear - No. Structural types are essentially types that can hold no secrets. It has to be public by definition (at least as specified in C++20, who know what the future will bring).